# Restore sql server 2000 database to 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server, restore

I am not a DBA. I will be doing this for the first time. So I am not sure what all I am supposed to do?

I will be restoring sql server 2000 database to sql server 2008. Are there anywhere step by step instructions to do this?

I know I am supposed to change compatibility mode, rebuild indexes on all the tables.

It will really help me if there are step by step instructions.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Voting to move this to ServerFault.com - our site for Administrators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SQL Server Management Studio to do this.

1. Right-click on the Databases node
2. Select "Restore Database"
3. Enter the name of the database to restore
4. Select "From device" and add the backup file in the next dialog
5. When returning to previous dialog, make sure to check the Restore check-box at the left side of the database name
6. Click "OK" to restore the database
7. Right-click the newly imported database and select properties
8. Select Options in the menu and on the right side you will get the option of changing the compatibility level.
9. Select the compability level required for your applications

Hope it helps!

Comment: I know these basic stepd but can you tell me what other scripts I am supposed to run after upgrade? like rebuild indexes on all tables or anything else?

Comment: User643062: Remember that logins are not imported, even thou users are (as you can't restore the old master db over the new master db, given the sql versions, iirc).

Comment: user75231: no need to run anything, it will work as it is.

Comment: One thing that I would normally do is to run sp_changedbowner to change dbo to an existing user.

Comment: user 3molo thanks for your quick reply. I know about logins not getting imported. When I ran test of restore last week and some of crystal reports were running very slow on this restore somebody asked me did you rebuild all indexes? update statcis? So I was not sure What all I need to do after upgrade?

Comment: Normally you don't **have** to rebuild indexes and update statistics, but if you are facing performance issues, it could be a smart thing to do. There are several ways of doing this. I normally create a maintenance plan in SQL 2008 to handle this for me.

Comment: Ole_Brun: can u please explaing me little bit about creating maintenance plan? As I told you other than writing stored procedures, triggers, queries and desining tables, views etc I haven't done any DBA tasks so far. Basially I am a vb and C# front end developer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ole_Brun:  Never mind I have been reading about maintenance plan on Miscrosoft now. Thanks!

Comment: @user75231 I believe this blog should get you started: [link](http://www.techbubbles.com/sql-server/creating-maintenance-plans-in-sql-server-2008-r2-2/)